# Weird Set.contains() behavior

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I initially started this as a test for a **theory-based, best-practices** question that I wanted to ask here, but in the process I found some interesting behavior in the java.Set class. Initially, I wanted to know any potential pitfalls of this approach, but now that I can see it doesn't work at all, **I'd like to know why.**

I have some objects that are containers for database objects for my app. The objects all have unique `integer id`'s, and `hashCode()` and `equals()` are defined by the integer ids (for storage in hashsets).

Well, I wanted the ability to check if a hashset contains the object given only the id.
Certainly, I could create a new instance of the object and check that way. But, just for kicks, I wanted to see if I could accomplish it. Of course, this is also trivial with a hashmap, so **this is really not an important question, just for fun and knowledge.**

So, I made a class, and tried to call `contains()` on an `integer`, instead of an instance of the object. Netbeans, of course, gives a fun warning for this

```
Suspicious call to java.util.Collection.contains:
Given object cannot contain instances of int (expected Person)
```

Ignoring the error and running the code, I was shocked to find that **Java does not even call the equals method.** I placed debugging `System.out.println()`s in my equals method to verify, and yep, it's not even being called.

In the code posted below, the expected output should be (if my theory was ***correct***):

> ```
> Here
> Yes
> Here
> Yes
> ```

or (if my theory was ***incorrect***):

> ```
> Here
> Yes
> Here
> No
> ```

However, the output is:

> ```
> Here
> Yes
> No
> ```

Notice, there's no "Here" before the "No" proving that the equals method is not even being called.

Can anyone shed light? I was always told to add this to `equals()` for efficiency:

```
if (!(obj instanceof Person))
    return false;
```

But if `equals()` is not even called in such a situation, then that would be pointless.

Here is the SSCCE:

Thanks for your time.

```
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     *
     * @author Ryan
     */
    public class Test7 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            class Person {
                public final int id;
                public final String name;

                public Person(int id, String name) {
                    this.id = id;
                    this.name = name;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    System.out.println("Here");
                    if (this == obj)
                        return true;
                    if (obj instanceof Person)
                        return id  == ((Person)obj).id;
                    else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                        return id == (Integer)obj;
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Returning False");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    return id;
                }
            }

            Set<Person> set = new LinkedHashSet<Person>();
            set.add(new Person(1, "Bob"));
            set.add(new Person(2, "George"));
            set.add(new Person(3, "Sam"));


            if(set.contains(new Person(1, "Bob")))
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");

            if(set.contains(1))
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
```

Comment: its skipping the equals because its calling integer.equals(e). From javadoc: (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to that fact that the **comparison is done on the provided object** not the elements in the set. From [HashSet#contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that **(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))**.

So in your example, you would be doing comparison *like* `integer.equals(person)`. So if your set contains `Person` objects, the `if(obj instanceof Integer)` condition will never be checked, but if your set contained  `Integer` objects, that condition would be satisfied and as such would be checked.

Comment: Brilliant! Yes that explains it perfectly. If `contains()` were based on `e.equals(o)`, then mine might work. But because it bases the equality on the given object (`o`), I'm out of luck. Great observation! This one had me really scratching my head.

Comment: This also helps me realize my `equals()` method is not symmetric. That is, `e.equals(o)` would return true but `o.equals(e)` would return false.